# How to auto increment a number of form "x.y.z" in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a variable with a value of `x.x.x`, I need a function that will first increment the rightmost value to `10`, and when it reaches `11`, increment the immediate left value. Same rules apply for all the values; when they reach `11`, they will increment the immediate left value. I need this for an automated build number in fastlane.

Comment: Could you add an example ?

Comment: `x.x.x` is invalid. What class is it? How do you increment `x` into `10`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That versioning scheme doesn't really make sense, as it's equivalent to just sequential `x` (just translated into undecimal), so why not just use that? Versions that look like `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH` use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) scheme, where increment in different version components reflects how much the version is changed from the previous one. This cannot be automated without regard to API changes. You could just increase the patch version, and require manual intervention if major or minor is increased. AFAIK there is no rule why you couldn't have `v0.0.1873`.

Comment: When `z` reaches `11`, does it reset to `0`?

Comment: I understand that you want `"0.0.10".increment #=> "0.1.0"` (instead of just `"0.0.11"`). Are you aware that this is not how semantic versioning works? I would argue that such a kind of versioning would be confusing and not useful at all. What do you try to achieve by designing an uncommon versioning schema like that?

Comment: Up to 11? Must be the Spinal Tap versioning scheme ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Simple splitting, incrementing, comparing and rejoining::

```
def increment_version(version)
  major, minor, patch = version.split('.').map(&:to_i)
  if (patch += 1) > 10
    patch = 0
    if (minor += 1) > 10
      minor = 0
      major += 1
    end
  end
  [major, minor, patch].join('.')
end
```

And test it:

```
{
  '0.0.9' => '0.0.10',
  '0.0.10' => '0.1.0',
  '0.10.9' => '0.10.10',
  '0.10.10' => '1.0.0'
}.each do |version, expected|
  puts "%-10s -> %-10s (should be %s)" % [version, increment_version(version), expected]
end
```

Outputs:

```
0.0.9      -> 0.0.10     (should be 0.0.10)
0.0.10     -> 0.1.0      (should be 0.1.0)
0.10.9     -> 0.10.10    (should be 0.10.10)
0.10.10    -> 1.0.0      (should be 1.0.0)
```

But as mentioned in the comments, this kind of versioning is against the whole idea of "x.y.z" type of versioning. As documented in [semver.org](https://semver.org) :

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

If you just autoincrement the version like the method above does, the version number will mean absolutely nothing and you would be better off just using a single running build number or the current time, like `build-20180213101500`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one 'a' is a string here
    a = '1.1.10'

```
def increment_built_num(current_built_num)
  b = current_built_num.split('.').map(&:to_i)

  b[2] += 1

  if (b[2] > 10)
    b[1] += 1
    b[2] = 0  # optional if want to reset
  end

  if (b[1] > 10)
    b[0] += 1
    b[1] = 0  # optional if want to reset
  end

  b.join('.')
end

a = increment_built_num(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if your versioning is what has been discussed in the comments, then your representation is really base-11:

```
def v_11(v)
  v.to_s(11).rjust(3,'0').chars.join('.').gsub('a','10')
end

version = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = -1
  loop do
    i += 1
    v = v_11(i)
    y << v
  end
end

#test
12.times { |v| puts version.next }

#0.0.0
#0.0.1
#0.0.2
#0.0.3
#0.0.4
#0.0.5
#0.0.6
#0.0.7
#0.0.8
#0.0.9
#0.0.10
#0.1.0
```

This converts a denary to a base-11 representation followed by string manipulation before using an enumerator to increment.